# Error query by id, Graphene Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make an query by id, I'm doing it like that, but I have the same error in the two options

First option

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    node = graphene.relay.Node.Field()
    user = graphene.Field(Users, id = graphene.Int())

    def resolve_user(self, args, context, info):
        query = Users.get_query(context)
        id = args.get('id')
        return query.get(id)
```

Second option

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    node = relay.Node.Field()
    user = SQLAlchemyConnectionField(Users)
    find_user = graphene.Field(lambda: Users, id = graphene.Int())

    def resolve_find_user(self, args, context, info):
        query = Users.get_query(context)
        print("Args--------------------",str(args))
        id = args.get('id')
        return query.filter(UsersModel.id == id).first()
```

Error

```
graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: resolve_find_user() got an unexpected keyword argument│'id'
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of my error [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/master/UPGRADE-v2.0.md) the documentaion of de new version 2.0

Comment: Please avoid [link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Your answer should actually answer the question.